# Photoshop text bounding box width and height

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, photoshop-scripting

How to get the width and height of text bounding box in Photoshop using ExtendScript

Answer (score 1):

To grab the bounding box of the currently selected paragraph text layer:

```
var t = activeDocument.activeLayer.textItem;
alert(t.width + ", " + t.height);
```

This is documented in the [JavaScript Scripting Reference](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-javascript-ref.pdf) (TextItem properties are listed starting on page 179)

Comment: Any idea how to do this if it's not paragraph text?